# Find active links parent and clone nested ul

Tags: jquery, html, css, clone, nested-lists

```
//This works! but I was trying to avoid the extra class  
$("a.active").parent().addClass("active");
$('li.active ul').clone().appendTo('.leftnav').removeClass();

// this does not work
$("a.active").parent(function () {
    $('this ul').clone().appendTo('.leftnav').removeClass();
})

// does not work either
var activeLink = $("a.active").parent();
$(activeLink('ul')).clone().appendTo('.leftnav').removeClass();
```

---

Can you add to the "this" by looking for its nest ul?

if not

what about placing it in a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution I found:

```
$('ul.nav a.active').parent().children('ul').clone().appendTo('.leftnav').removeClass();
```

- I found the active a
- Then found its parent which was an li
- Then I looked in the li's children and found the ul
- I was then able to clone that ul and append it to the leftnav div

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a.active, try a:active. the ':active' is a pseudo class added by the browsers, but ".active" refers to an actual class added by the developer.

I should also note that :active only works on the a (anchor) tags, not li's, with li's you'd have to use your .active class.